# Define ringtone by area code or number sequence

Tags: ringtone, personalization

My questions seems a little "exotic", but is it possible to define a ringtone by area code or number sequence? I have many buddies in Germany and in the USA. I would like to define the following schema:

```
buddy A: +49 abcde 12345 ==> known contact ==> ringtone A
buddy B: +49 abcde 23456 ==> known contact ==> ringtone B
buddy X: +49 abcde xxxxx ==> unknown contact ==> ringtone of "+49abcde"

buddy D: +1 256 5551111 ==> known contact ==> ringtone D
buddy E: +1 256 5552222 ==> known contact ==> rinftone E
buddy Y: +1 256 yyyyyyy ==> unknown contact ==> ringtone "sweet home Alabama"
```

I tried to define a contact for `+49abcde` and similar, but the specific ringtone is not used.

Has anyone seen any app or anything to accomplish this?

I have a Nokia Lumia 830, Windows Phone 8.1 Update 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is currently not possible. You can only set ringtones for a specific contact. You can post your suggestion on http://windowsphone.uservoice.com.